# как вернуть тип грузовика с наименьшей грузоподъемностью, и если вес превышает лимит вернуть сообщение WeightTooHighException в этом задании?

Tags: java, java-stream, enum

Есть грузовик `Truck`, у которого задана максимальная грузоподъемность.

Грузовики делятся на 3 типа в зависимости от грузоподъемности:

- `Pickup`        - до 2 тонн
- `SmallBoxTruck` - до 12 тонн
- `SemiTrailer`   - до 20 тонн

Возвращает тип грузовика с наименьшей грузоподъемностью, который сможет перевести заданный вес.

Если вес слишком большой, то метод должен кинуть `WeightTooHighException` с сообщением "слишком большой вес".

Пример:

```
1_000 -> Pickup   (для одной тонны достаточно пикапа)
```

Вы можете решить это задание как через Stream, так и через цикл.

Какой код выйдет проще и легче для понимания, тот и используйте.

Подсказка: Доступные значения в enum можно перебирать через метод `values()`

Совет: Нажмите `Ctrl+Q` (`Cmd+Q`) чтобы увидеть комментарии с форматированием.

Я пока обычным методом не могу даже пройти задание, не пойму,  как правильно вернуть `WeightTooHighException`

```java
public static TruckType getTypeByWeight(int weight) {

    if (TruckType.Pickup.canHandleWeight(weight)) {
        System.out.println(TruckType.Pickup);
        return TruckType.Pickup;
    }
    if (TruckType.SmallBoxTruck.canHandleWeight(weight)) {
        System.out.println(TruckType.SmallBoxTruck);
        return TruckType.SmallBoxTruck;
    }
    if (TruckType.SemiTrailer.canHandleWeight(weight)) {
        System.out.println(TruckType.SemiTrailer);
        return TruckType.SemiTrailer;
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

Ссылка с заданием https://github.com/lislon/streams-assignments
задание task4 1ое

Comment: и как сделать через stream

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: там не нужен else. просто бросайте исключение последним действием

Comment: "и как сделать через stream" - может быть, есть еще какие-нибудь заказы?

Answer (score 0):

Массив значений, который возвращается из `TruckType.values()`, имеет фиксированный порядок, поэтому в задании и сказано использовать цикл или поток Stream API, соответственно какой тип грузовика будет найден раньше, тот и должен быть возвращен:

```java
public static TruckType getTypeByWeight(int weight) {
    for (TruckType tt : TruckType.values()) {
        if (tt.canHandleWeight(weight)) {
            System.out.println(TruckType.Pickup);
            return tt;
        }
    }
    throw new WeightTooHighException("No truck type for weight = " + weight);
}
```

---

Аналогично можно использовать Stream API:

- получить поток значений `TruckType` при помощи [`Arrays::stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-)
- отфильтровать этот поток, используя [`Stream::filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)
- взять первое значение, используя [`Stream::findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--), которое возвращает `Optional<TruckType>`
- использовать [`Optional::orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X extends Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-), чтобы вернуть найденный тип, или выбросить требуемое исключение.

Данной информации должно быть достаточно для самостоятельного решения данного упражнения при помощи Stream API.